# Чи варто вживати слово "коп"?

Tags: вживання-слів

Сьогодні почув як у новинах було вжито слово "копи". Ввівши його в пошуку в Гуглі, побачив, що зараз воно часто вживається у випусках новин (наприклад [тут](https://tsn.ua/ukrayina/kopi-u-hmelnickomu-zapustili-kreativniy-fleshmob-178-1153797.html) і [тут](https://vikna.stb.ua/ua/episode/kop-na-kopa-u-zaporizhzhi/)). Саме слово походить від англійського "[cop](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cop)" - слово, яким називають в США співробітників поліції. Питання у тому чи взагалі варто вживати це слово і чи все ж краще вживати слово "поліцейський" (адже самого слова "коп" немає в СУМі, навідмінно від "поліцейського", а в англійських тлумачних словниках "сop" має примітку "informal")? І можливо в українській мові є якийсь відповідник до цього слова? [Словотвір](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/kop) пропонує "вартовець" або "варт", однак ці два варіанти не обов'язково означатимуть "людину, яка працює у поліції".

Comment: Польський відповідник патрульної поліції - straż miejska [страж міста] тож можете додати до цьго списку й "страж". Якщо Ви почитаєте походження слова "cop", то зрозумієте, що воно не лише не має жодного прямого зв'язку з "людиною, яка працює у поліції", а й взагалі пішло від "copper" - мідь. Те ж саме, як би ми називали наших поліцейських "мідяки" :) Так що такий зв'язок взагалі не обов'язковий.

Comment: Слово "copper" використовувалося як сленг серед вуличних злодіїв, щоб позначити офіцера поліції і таки так, воно пов'язане із міддю, бо в той час у цих офіцерів були мідні гудзики. Хоча за іншою версією слово походить від латинського "capere", тобто "заарештувати". Я так розумію це щось на кшталт російського "мєнт", от тільки якщо це так, то чи варто його взагалі вживати, ще й у новинах і чи все ж таки є якесь відповідне слово в українській мові.

Comment: Див. також: [«Поліцейський, поліцай, поліціянт чи поліціант?»](/q/4880).